# Why can't I UPDATE MySQL with an string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have three vars that I want to update to an mysql database.

```
var rank = "Bronze II";
var wins = 304;
var level = 51;
```

Why can't I update the database with my `Bronze II` string? If I change it to an number it's working.

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query("UPDATE Users SET Rank = " + rank + ", Wins = " + wins + ", Level = " + level + " WHERE SteamID64 = " + `${row.SteamID64}` +"");
    connection.release();
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: SQL syntax requires strings to be quoted.

Comment: Relevant xkcd: [Exploits of a mom](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Use placeholders instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Why do you have a template literal with just a single expression? If you're going to use template literals, do it for the whole query.

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: Imagine what your constructed query looks like: `UPDATE Users SET Rank = Bronze II, Wins = 304, ...` — would you expect that to work? The string has to be quoted.

Comment: whoops... nothing more to say

Comment: @Barmar Usage of template literals in SQL queries is a terrible idea, it's much better to show the proper way - prepared statements.

Comment: @MatSz I know, I already said to use placeholders. I was just reacting to the weird template literal at the end that just surrounds a single value. It's no different from just concatenating the value by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a prepared query instead.

```
connection.query('UPDATE users SET foo = ?, bar = ?, baz = ? WHERE id = ?', ['a', 'b', 'c', userId], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // ...
});
```

With your data:

```
connection.query("UPDATE Users SET Rank = ?, Wins = ?, Level = ? WHERE SteamID64 = ?", [ rank, wins, level, row.steamID64 ]);
```

This will improve the security of your application and help you avoid similar problems in the future. (Imagine if your data had a `"` character inside?)

You should do this to all queries that rely on external input, instead of concatenating strings.